# Google Maps навигация

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Помогите исправить ошибку

> `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener
>   (com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener)' on a null object reference
>   at v.com.example.com.tst2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)`

line 75 NullPointerException

Пример кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Marker selectedMarker;
private Animator animator = new Animator();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    Button ResetMarker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clearmarker);

    ResetMarker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearMarkers();
        }
    });

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animator.startAnimation(false);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animator.stopAnimation();
        }
    });

    loadMap();
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            addMarkerToMap(latLng);
            animator.startAnimation(false);
        }
    });
}

public void clearMarkers() {
    googleMap.clear();
    markers.clear();
}

protected void removeSelectedMarker() {
    this.markers.remove(this.selectedMarker);
    this.selectedMarker.remove();
}

protected void addMarkerToMap(LatLng latLng) {
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("title").snippet("snippet"));
    markers.add(marker);
}

public class Animator implements Runnable {
    private static final int ANIMATE_SPEEED = 1500;
    private static final int ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN = 1000;
    private static final int BEARING_OFFSET = 20;
    private final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    int currentIndex = 0;
    float tilt = 90;
    float zoom = 15.5f;
    boolean upward=true;
    long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    LatLng endLatLng = null;
    LatLng beginLatLng = null;
    boolean showPolyline = false;
    private Marker trackingMarker;

    public void reset() {
        resetMarkers();
        start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        currentIndex = 0;
        endLatLng = getEndLatLng();
        beginLatLng = getBeginLatLng();

    }

    private void resetMarkers() {
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        trackingMarker.remove();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(animator);
    }

    private void highLightMarker(int index) {
        highLightMarker(markers.get(index));
    }

    private void highLightMarker(Marker marker) {
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        selectedMarker=marker;
    }

    public void initialize(boolean showPolyLine) {
        reset();
        this.showPolyline = showPolyLine;
        highLightMarker(0);
        if (showPolyLine) {
            polyLine = initializePolyLine();
        }
        // We first need to put the camera in the correct position for the first run (we need 2 markers for this).....
        LatLng markerPos = markers.get(0).getPosition();
        LatLng secondPos = markers.get(1).getPosition();
        setupCameraPositionForMovement(markerPos, secondPos);
    }

    private void setupCameraPositionForMovement(LatLng markerPos, LatLng secondPos) {
        float bearing = bearingBetweenLatLngs(markerPos,secondPos);
        trackingMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPos)
                .title("title")
                .snippet("snippet"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(markerPos)
                .bearing(bearing + BEARING_OFFSET)
                .tilt(90)
                .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom >=16 ? googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom : 16)
                .build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN,
                new CancelableCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        System.out.println("finished camera");
                        Log.e("animator before reset", animator +"");
                        animator.reset();
                        Log.e("animator after reset", animator +"");
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.post(animator);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        System.out.println("cancelling camera");
                    }
                });
    }

    public void navigateToPoint(LatLng latLng, boolean animate) {
        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).build();
        changeCameraPosition(position, animate);
    }

    private void changeCameraPosition(CameraPosition cameraPosition, boolean animate) {
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        if (animate) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        } else {
            googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

    private Location convertLatLngToLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Location loc = new Location("someLoc");
        loc.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
        loc.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
        return loc;
    }

    private float bearingBetweenLatLngs(LatLng begin,LatLng end) {
        Location beginL= convertLatLngToLocation(begin);
        Location endL= convertLatLngToLocation(end);
        return beginL.bearingTo(endL);
    }
    public void toggleStyle() {
        if (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL == googleMap.getMapType()) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    private Polyline polyLine;
    private PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    private Polyline initializePolyLine() {
        rectOptions.add(markers.get(0).getPosition());
        return googleMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Add the marker to the polyline.
     */
    private void updatePolyLine(LatLng latLng) {
        List<LatLng> points = polyLine.getPoints();
        points.add(latLng);
        polyLine.setPoints(points);
    }
    public void stopAnimation() {
        animator.stop();
    }

    public void startAnimation(boolean showPolyLine) {
        if (markers.size()>2) {
            animator.initialize(showPolyLine);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        double t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/ANIMATE_SPEEED);
        Log.w("interpolator", t +"");
        double lat = t * endLatLng.latitude + (1-t) * beginLatLng.latitude;
        double lng = t * endLatLng.longitude + (1-t) * beginLatLng.longitude;
        Log.w("lat. lng", lat + "," + lng +"");
        LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        Log.w("newPosition", newPosition +"");

        trackingMarker.setPosition(newPosition);
        if (showPolyline) {
            updatePolyLine(newPosition);
        }

        // It's not possible to move the marker + center it through a cameraposition update while another camerapostioning was already happening.
        //navigateToPoint(newPosition,tilt,bearing,currentZoom,false);
        //navigateToPoint(newPosition,false);

        if (t< 1) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 16);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Move to next marker.... current = " + currentIndex + " and size = " + markers.size());
            // imagine 5 elements -  0|1|2|3|4 currentindex must be smaller than 4
            if (currentIndex<markers.size()-2) {
                currentIndex++;
                endLatLng = getEndLatLng();
                beginLatLng = getBeginLatLng();
                start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                LatLng begin = getBeginLatLng();
                LatLng end = getEndLatLng();
                float bearingL = bearingBetweenLatLngs(begin, end);
                highLightMarker(currentIndex);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(end) // changed this...
                        .bearing(bearingL  + BEARING_OFFSET)
                        .tilt(tilt)
                        .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                        .build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                        ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN,
                        null
                );
                start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                mHandler.postDelayed(animator, 16);
            } else {
                currentIndex++;
                highLightMarker(currentIndex);
                stopAnimation();
            }
        }
    }
    private LatLng getEndLatLng() {
        return markers.get(currentIndex+1).getPosition();
    }
    private LatLng getBeginLatLng() {
        return markers.get(currentIndex).getPosition();
    }
    private void adjustCameraPosition() {
        if (upward) {
            if (tilt<90) {
                tilt ++;
                zoom-=0.01f;
            } else {
                upward=false;
            }
        } else {
            if (tilt>0) {
                tilt --;
                zoom+=0.01f;
            } else {
                upward=true;
            }
        }
    }
};

private void loadMap() {
    try {
        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: вы предлагаете посчитать 75 строк? Укажите строчку где падает и что Вы при это пытаетесь сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли инициализировать переменную **googleMap**